# Oracle SQL - SUM aggregate not working in LEVEL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query where it has an output when using `count` but no output when using `sum`

```
select to_char(counter)
from (select level counter from dual connect by level <= 1000000)
where counter =
(select sum(a.amount) from table a)
```

I'm wondering it's because the query only supports outputs of whole numbers? I am expecting to have outputs with decimals.

I am using this as a table value set in Oracle HCM, if anyone's familiar with that. It's why I don't have the aggregate in the SELECT statement as it doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your subquery is returning rows? Because SUM of an empty set is null not zero, eg

```
SQL> select to_char(counter)
  2  from (  select level counter from dual connect by level <= 1000000 )
  3  where counter =
  4     (select sum(deptno) from scott.emp);

TO_CHAR(COUNTER)
----------------------------------------
310

SQL> select to_char(counter)
  2  from (  select level counter from dual connect by level <= 1000000 )
  3  where counter =
  4     (select sum(deptno) from scott.emp where 1=0);

no rows selected
```

Comment: Yes. I ran a sample that has a count of 2 (using `count`) but when I try to find the sum of those two items, using `sum`, there is no output. Maybe the problem is the query in the from clause.

Comment: we need to see your test case - top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

Your query says: Create all integers from 1 to 1,000,000 and of these show me the one that matches exactly the total amount of the table. So if that total is 123.45, you will get no row. If that amount is -123, you will get no row. If that amount is 1,000,001 you will get no row.

If you simply want the total, but you can have aggregations only in subqueries for some weird reason, just do

```
select * from (select sum(amount) as total from table) t;
```

Comment: Is possible to make the query support numbers with decimals?

Comment: Yours or mine? Mine does. In yours you would have to create all possible decimal numbers. If you know this can only be up to two decimal places, then `... connect by level <= 100000000 ) where counter / 100 = ...`. It seems almost insane though to create 100 million rows only to match the one value you already have.